# How should I type my sqlite connection and cursor in a python class before I provide meaningful values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, mypy

I just joined a new company that uses mypy to enforce types in python, and I'd like to understand how to properly type a sqlite db connection in a db class.

Previously I would've done something like this (I am only defining init() and connect() for brevity):

```
import sqlite3

class DBConn:
    def __init__(self, db_path):
        self.db_path = db_path
        self.conn = None
        self.cursor = None

    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            return True
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print("Error connecting to database: {e}")
            return False
```

Now I have modified that code to be as follows (according to typing):

```py
import sqlite3

class DBConn:
    def __init__(self, db_path: str) -> None:
        self.db_path = db_path
        self.conn = None
        self.cursor = None

    def connect(self) -> bool:
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor() # warning is here
            return True
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print("Error connecting to database: {e}")
            return False
```

Once I have made these updates, I am getting a warning from mypy that a "None" type object cannot have an attribute "cursor" where I assign self.cursor. If I modify the initial value in init to an empty str for example, I get the same message with "str" instead of None.

How should I properly type these self vars before instantiation so that I can avoid this warning? Or do I just ignore it? Or is there a better/more pythonic way to code this?

Any suggestions are much appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, you need to use explicit type annotations or else you are relying on mypy's inference, and it can *only* infer that the attribute will have the type you assigned to it, in this case, `None`. Now, since oyu are *assigning `None`* this attribute needs to be a *union* of None and the Cursor type. Of course, using union's is annoying, because now mypy will copmlain every time you try to use `.cursor_attribute` because you haven't checked if it is None or not. But that is actually just an issue with this design.

Comment: " If I modify the initial value in init to an empty str for example, I get the same message with "str" instead of None." again, *of course*.  That's actually the *whole point of type annotations and static type checking*. It's telling you, "you told me this is a string, but now, you are trying to access an attribute that strings don't have".

Comment: How do you solve this? By using dependency injection. Your class should tae a connection *as an argument*.

Comment: Also note, you *should* have gotten an error on the previous line: `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Connection", variable has type "None")` for the same reason. So this is clearly not a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga! So my connect() method should move to whatever function implements the DB class? That seems like an uncoupled way to do it because I need to move the connection logic out of the class. Is there any way to keep that within the class?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did not get that error, so this is a minimal reproducible example according to my code

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly, but sure, you don't have to use dependency injection. You can do things the way you have here, but you need to type annotate things as `typing.Optional[sqlite3.Connection]` (shorthand for `typing.Union[None, sqlite3.Connection]`), for example, but then, it will complain every time you do `self.connection.whatever` since **`None` is a poosible value**, so you have to do `if self.connection is not None: self.connection.whatever`, but again, that is the only way to make your code *type safe*. mypy is correctly pointing out that otherwise, you code is not type safe

Comment: What version of mypy are you using? Obviously, you are missing things from your example here (since, just as an example, `sqlite3` would throw a name-error, and mypy would warn about it, so at the very least you've omitted imports)

Comment: Im only importing sqlite3. Fixed

Comment: Then on `mypy` version `1.0.0` I get that error, and I'm pretty sure on any recent mypy version, you should get that error. because it is a basic type error. So again, you really must provide a [mcve]

Comment: The mypy version is 1.1.1

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga at this point with your passive aggressive hyperlink it seems more like you're trying to pick apart what Im doing than helping...what benefit would I have not not provide an MRE? This is my code and I have correctly characterized the error according to my code. If you'd like to provide a helpful answer instead, feel free and I will upvote it! :)

Comment: Here you go, demonstrating that (as anyone would expect) that line makes mypy complain: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&gist=81e7d9ae6b938a75184bdb2cbd1c8d97

Comment: Congrats, I hope that makes you feel special. Still doesn't solve my problem...I appreciate a healthy conversation but we've moved beyond that. I will keep exploring. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know what you motivation is, I can only point out that what you had was indeed not a [mcve], and you seem to aknowledge that since you edited to make it one, but yet, I still cannot reproduce the behavior you are reporting. if I upgrade to mypy 1.1.1, I get, as expected, two errors.

Comment: I didn't add the import because it should be self explanatory. I've updated it. Even if that error is happening, I also need to solve it for the same reason. The solution should be the same. So what is it?

Comment: You must understand, it is critical that we can reproduce the behavior you are reporting if you want help. Despite all that, I provided you with two different options for how to approach this. In your mind the fact that I posted a hyperlink makes this conversion "unhealthy". I wish you good luck with your attitude towards people providing you with information when you ask for help.

Comment: I reported it as I am seeing it in my code. If you see an additional error, then I'd love your input for that too! Can you please provide your solution as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga for reference if you'd like to know, I've posted the correct solution below. I added an Optional type to both the connection and cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for the answer in the future, you can use the MyPy type Optional as follows:

```py
import sqlite3
from typing import Optional


class DB:
    def __init__(self, db_path: str) -> None:
        self.db_path = db_path
        self.conn: Optional[sqlite3.Connection] = None
        self.cursor: Optional[sqlite3.Cursor] = None

    def connect(self) -> bool:
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_path)
            self.conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            print("Connection successful")
            return True
        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print(f"Error connecting to database: {e}")
            return False
```